# Contracting dataset to only hold unique values for a variable

Tags: stata

Assuming I have the following dataset as a toy example:

```
clear

input str32 Country Population_1 Population_2 
"United States of America" 3999 .
"United States of America" .  3447
"Afghanistan" 544 .
"Afghanistan" . 727
"Belgium" 7546 .
"Belgium" . 992
"China" 10000 .
"China" .  12000
end
```

I want to shrink the dataset so that there is just one unique value for country.

My final dataset should look as follows:

```
Country                    Population_1   Population_2
United States of America       3999           3447
Afghanistan                     544            727
Belgium                        7546            992
China                         10000          12000
```

I tried to use the `collapse` command but did not get the expected outcome. The command `duplicates drop` does not work either, as I it does not obtain the observations from `Population_2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
collapse Pop*, by(Country) 

list, abbreviate(12)

     +--------------------------------------------------------+
     |                  Country   Population_1   Population_2 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |              Afghanistan            544            727 |
  2. |                  Belgium           7546            992 |
  3. |                    China          10000          12000 |
  4. | United States of America           3999           3447 |
     +--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
generate Population_ = .

by Country, sort: replace Population_ = Population_2 if Population_1 == .
by Country, sort: replace Population_ = Population_1 if Population_2 == .

by Country: generate time = _n

drop Population_1 Population_2

reshape wide Population_, i(Country) j(time)
```

Answer (score 0):

The *community-contributed* command `gcollapse` can also preserve wanted variables in the dataset:

```
gcollapse (sum) Pop*, merge replace by(Country)
duplicates drop Country, force
```

Comment: This is an answer to a different question.

Comment: this was my original question - my original dataset has many other variables that I want to keep, and only want to `collapse` the population variables. Should I create a new question?

Comment: It may well have been in your mind but we don't know that and you haven't edited the original question. More crucially, a `collapse` of some variables but not others makes no sense. If a variable is numerically constant within (say) countries, its constant value will be the mean from `collapse`; if the distinct values of a string variable are of use or interest, they belong inside `by()`.  As the original author of `duplicates` I view with alarm and without approval the use of the `force` option here without a rationale; as in the rest of life force is at best the last resort of the desperate.

Comment: @NickCox makes a good point. Note that you can also do the same with couple more lines of code and only using built-in commands.

Comment: instead of the `force` option, is it wise to just use: `drop if missing(City)`